# How to share large set of files between kuberntes pods

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I have a large set of **read-only** configuration files (around 4k) which is used by the microservice to process some XML files and supposed to be read via **Apache Commons Configuration**.

These files are of the following types:

- Properties file
- XML
- dtd
- xfo
- xslt

5 of these files will need some environment variables to be substituted in their content, such as third party software location, or different services URL based on the environment the files are deployed in.

Now, I need to make these files available for 4 microservices at run time.

I'm using fabric8.io maven docker plugin with dockerfile for image generation.
Kubernetes, helm, Jenkinsfile, and ArgoCD for the spring-boot microservices CD/CI.

The 2 challenges that I'm facing is how to substitute the variables inside of these static files, and how to make these files available for each pod.

I have three solutions in mind but **I would like to know what is the best/optimal 12-factor approach for this problem.**

Solution 1: is to deploy the files as a separate pod and allow other pods to access to some volume mount that it provides.

Solution  2: Add the files to the microservice image during the docker image build.

Solution  3: Add the files as a container of each microservice pod.

Comment: It seems like you have at least two separate concerns here, input validation through a DTD (not an XML Schema?) and formatted output construction via XSL:FO.  Can you do these once at the perimeter of your system, and use some neutral format to communicate between services?  (Which could still be XML, but you'd only need the `.dtd`/`.xsd` files, and you could easily `COPY` them into your images.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I have updated the question body, The problem is this is a migration, and the old system is using filesystem paths to read these configs for the namely tasks you mentioned.

Comment: I was wondering about a solution in yout pipeline: You could create a stage in jenkins that read the file, replace with the correct variables and create a configMap to be access by your pods... You can keep the tracing and versioning of your files. But the question is, all your pods could read the same file, with the same vars?

Answer (score 1):

You could upload this file to a kubernetes ConfigMap.

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  haproxy.cfg: "complete file contents"
```

It can contain entire file, and mount this file in a pod directory

```
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /usr/local/etc/haproxy
        name: config
  volumes:
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: env-config-haproxy
        items:
          - key: haproxy.cfg
            path: haproxy.cfg
```

Comment: So, basically create 4000 ConfigMaps (one for each file)?

Comment: you can have multiple files per ConfigMap, each inside a different key

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution: mounting the files as a volume (backed by cloud storage) and substituting values on-access within the service and that's a solution I'd go with by default.

Solutions 1 and especially 3 add a lot of complexity. Solution 2 may be a good choice too, however to choose the best option you really need to answer another question - how are the config files and env substitutions changing with respect to the application container versions?

i.e. When you change the files, should all of the services get new versions?

Comment: Yes they should.